# Fixed Height for Navigation bar on UITableView scroll

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, tableview

**Problem:**

I would like the navigation bar and large title to remain fixed when scrolling the tableView. How can I set it programmatically so that when the tableView is scrolled the navigation bar does not drag up/down or hide the large title?

**Code:**

```
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        setupTableView()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.separatorInset = .zero
        tableView.layoutMargins = .zero
        self.tableView.layoutMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
     
    }
    
    func setupTableView() {
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.separatorColor = .label
        tableView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        tableView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        //tableView.bounces = false
        tableView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = true
        tableView.clipsToBounds = true
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "ChatTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
       tableView.register(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChatTableViewCell")
   
    }

func configNavBar() {
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .black
        navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .black
        
        self.title = "Bitcoin"
     
        let navBarAppearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
        //navBarAppearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
        navBarAppearance.shadowColor = .clear
        navBarAppearance.shadowImage = UIImage()
        navBarAppearance.backgroundColor = .black
        navBarAppearance.largeTitleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
        
        navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = navBarAppearance
        navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = navBarAppearance

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Log out", style: .done, target: self, action: #selector(didTapLogout))
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem?.tintColor = .systemGray  
    }
```

I am programmatically setting the table view like so. I would like the navigation bar to remain static when the table view is scrolled.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationitem/largetitledisplaymode/always

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with this simple line, I don't know why ( I tried searching but couldn't find anything that justifies it ) but if you add a blank UIView in your view, the navigation bar remain static. Add below line in viewDidLoad:

```
view.addSubview(UIView())
```

Comment: From my understanding if the addSubview(tableView) is the first thing loaded in the hierarchy the navigation controller will not remain fixed. If you simply put the above line of code before your addSubview(tableView) it will not longer be the first loaded and you nav controller will be fixed.

Comment: @husharoonie I think you're right, it's the first plausible explanation I've read